# Linq to Entities - Delete / Add related data (many to many relationship)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have places - with related tags:

have a Place model:

```
public virtual int PlaceID { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

and a related Tag model:

```
public virtual int TagID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual string NamePlural { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }
```

many to many relationship.

So for example - a place could have a 'bar' and a 'cafe' tag. (and many places could have those tags also).

I can add places with related tags fine. However, how can I manipulate the tags that are related to places with Linq? (add / delete / edit).

Also - if I try and save a place model, with related tags - the place is updated but not the tags - how could I do this?

```
place.Tags = SelectedTags
db.Entry(ptvm.place).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use micromanagement with entity state of entities only if you know what and why are you doing.

In this case, you should give control of it to entity framework.

```
        db.Places.Attach(place);
        context.Entry(place).Collection(p => p.Tags).Load();

        foreach(var tag in SelectedTags)
        {
            place.Tags.Add(tag);
        }            
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Additional note: You cannot change navigation property `ICollection` to new collection. You can only add, remove and clear. If you want to remove or clear this collection, you should load it from database before.

Comment: Thanks - what do you mean by micromanagement? Lets say a place has 2 tags 'cafe' and 'bar' - and I want to remove 'cafe' and add 'restaurant'. Should I clear all tags first then add 'bar' and 'restaurant'? What's the best way to do that?

Comment: 1. Micromanagement is when you manually change EntityState to modified for all modified entities. 2. If i where you i will clear and add bar and restaurant.

Comment: I've implemented it and get this on 'place.Tags.Add(tag): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." - however the tag ISNT null during debugging

Comment: It is due to navigation property is not loaded. You should load it. I update answer.

Comment: thanks - I now get this: The property 'Tags' on type 'Place' is a collection navigation property. The Collection method should be used instead of the Reference method.

Comment: Follow its recommendation and use Collection instead Reference :). I Update answer.

Comment: thanks :) - this "But if you want to remove or clear this collection, you should load it from database before." - does that mean I can't just load the tags posted back from the page - that I have to load from the database instead? Why is that?

Comment: It is because EF should delete notrelevant links. But it is not know about them before Load.